# Importing a module under a module (pandas.io.data)

Tags: python, pandas, import, module

I've just encountered something that bothers me.
I always thought that importing a 'parent' module should import everything under it.
But, when running:

```
import pandas
pandas.io.data
```

I get an error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data'`.

However running:

```
import pandas.io.data
```

Leads to no error and the module is imported.
Could someone please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that `pandas.io` is a submodule of the `pandas` package. Subpackages or submodules are not imported automatically, although you can do this in the `__init__.py` of your module if you wish to (usually you don't want to do this).

[Packaging](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#packages) in python is fairly simple. If a folder has an `__init__.py` file, it's treated as a package. In this file you can lay out any initialization routines for your package. The file can also be empty. If a subfolder in your package contains its own `__init__.py`, this folder is considered to be a subpackage.

If you look that the [pandas folder structure](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/tree/master/pandas) you'll see that `io` is a subpackage. The main [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/__init__.py) does not import `pandas.io.data` which is why you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

"import" does not import child modules.
You can write:

```
from pandas import *
```

but it is not recommended, since it violates the principle "Explicit is better than implicit".